# How to subtract hours from a date in Oracle so it affects the day also

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I'm trying to subtract date from Oracle so it even effect the day as well. For example, if 
the timestamp is 01/June/2015 00 hours and if I subtract 2 hours, I want to be able to go to to 31/May/2014 22 hours.

I tried

```
to_char(sysdate-(2/11), 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24')
```

but it only subtracts the hour; it does not touch the day itself.

Comment: What makes you think `-(2/11)` subtracts 2 hours?  It is not an obvious notation.  It looks like it might subtract `0.22` units of some sort — I reserve judgement on whether that's days or seconds or some other unit.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: in Oracle an expression `date_value - integer` always means `date_value - number of days`. Fractional values are interpreted as hours. However 2/11 is a pretty obfuscated way of defining the expected value. I personally always use ANSI interval literals for something like that: `sysdate - interval '2' hour`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Thanks — that makes sense.  The basic unit of an Oracle DATE is days and time is fractions of a day.  My memory is rotten; 2/11 = 0.1818181818… and 2/9 = 0.2222222222…  It still doesn't seem that 2/11 is a way to specify 2 hours even so (it is somewhat over 4 hours).

Answer (score 76):

Others have commented on the (incorrect) use of `2/11` to specify the desired interval.

I personally however prefer writing things like that using ANSI `interval` literals which makes *reading* the query much easier:

```
sysdate - interval '2' hour
```

It also has the advantage of being portable, many DBMS support this. Plus I don't have to fire up a calculator to find out how many hours the expression means - I'm pretty bad with mental arithmetics ;)

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
SELECT to_char(sysdate - (2 / 24), 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24') FROM DUAL
```

To test it using a new date instance:

```
SELECT to_char(TO_DATE('11/06/2015 00:00','dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI') - (2 / 24), 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL
```

Output is: 06-10-2015 22:00, which is the previous day.

Answer (score 6):

> sysdate-(2/11)

A day consists of `24 hours`. So, to subtract `2 hours` from a day you need to divide it by `24`:

```
DATE_value - 2/24
```

Using `interval` for the same:

```
DATE_value - interval '2' hour
```

Answer (score 1):

`date - n` will subtract n days form given date. In order to subtract hrs you need to convert it into day buy dividing it with 24. In your case it should be `to_char(sysdate - (2 + 2/24), 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24')`. This will subract 2 days and 2 hrs from sysdate.

Answer (score 1):

you should divide hours by 24 not 11
like this:
`select to_char(sysdate - 2/24, 'dd-mon-yyyy HH24') from dual`