# How to take yesterdays datetime in Oracle with specific time?

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I need to take yesterdays value like:

```
18-11-2018 06:00:00
```

```sql
select (systimestamp - 1) as ts_bytes from dual;
```

where time is fixed.

Comment: Try `Systimestamp - INTERVAL '1' DAY `

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to subtract hours from a date in Oracle so it affects the day also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772434/how-to-subtract-hours-from-a-date-in-oracle-so-it-affects-the-day-also)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this:

```
select TRUNC(systimestamp - 1) + INTERVAL '6' HOUR as ts_bytes 
from dual;
```

or

```
TRUNC(systimestamp) - INTERVAL '18' HOUR
```

or if you prefer `DATE` values rather than `TIMESTAMP`

```
select TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1) + 6/24 as ts_bytes 
from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want then time at midnight (00:00:00) of yesterday then truncate the current timestamp to the start of today and then subtract one day:

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSTIMESTAMP) - INTERVAL '1' DAY as ts_bytes
FROM   DUAL;
```

If you want a specific HH:MM:SS time then add an interval with that time:

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSTIMESTAMP) - INTERVAL '1' DAY + INTERVAL '12:34:56' HOUR TO SECOND as ts_bytes
FROM   DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select to_char(trunc(sysdate-1),’dd-mm-yyyy’)||’ 06:00:00’ as tyme from dual;
```

This is funny but should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1' DAY   AS yesterday
FROM    dual;
```

try this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).